# Cant Pickle memoized class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, memoization, funcy

Here is the code I am using

```
import funcy

@funcy.memoize
class mystery(object):

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

feat = mystery(1)

with open('num.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(feat,f)
```

Which is giving me the following error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.mystery'>: it's not the 
same object as __main__.mystery
```

I am hoping to 1) understand why this is happening, and 2) find a solution that allows me to pickle the object (without removing the memoization). Ideally the solution would not change the call to pickle.

Running python 3.6 with funcy==1.10

Comment: What should happen when you load a pickled instance? Should it be added to the memo?

Comment: it doesnt really matter to me

Comment: By the way, applying a function decorator to a class is a bad idea for a variety of reasons. Try `isinstance(feat, mystery)` - you might expect to get `True` as output, but it'll actually throw an error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you've applied a decorator designed for functions to a class. The result is not a class, but a function that wraps up a call to the class. This causes a number of problems (e.g., as pointed out by Aran-Fey in the comments, you can't `isinstance(feat, mystery)`, because `mystery`).

But the particular problem you care about is that you can't pickle instances of inaccessible classes.

In fact, that's basically what the error message is telling you:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.mystery'>: it's not the 
same object as __main__.mystery
```

Your `feat` thinks its type is `__main__.mystery`, but that isn't a type at all, it's the function returned by the decorator that wraps that type.

---

The easy way to fix this would be to find a class decorator meant that does what you want. It might be called something like `flyweight` instead of `memoize`, but I'm sure plenty of examples exist.

---

But you can build a flyweight class by just memoizing the constructor, instead of memoizing the class:

```
class mystery:
    @funcy.memoize
    def __new__(cls, num):
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
```

… although you probably want to move the initialization into the constructor in that case. Otherwise, calling `mystery(1)` and then `mystery(1)` will return the same object as before, but also reinitialize it with `self.num = 1`, which is at best wasteful, and at worst incorrect. So:

```
class mystery:
    @funcy.memoize
    def __new__(cls, num):
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        self.num = num
        return self
```

---

And now:

```
>>> feat = mystery(1)
>>> feat
<__main__.mystery at 0x10eeb1278>
>>> mystery(2)
<__main__.mystery at 0x10eeb2c18>
>>> mystery(1)
<__main__.mystery at 0x10eeb1278>
```

And, because the type of `feat` is now a class that's accessible under the module-global name `mystery`, `pickle` will have no problem with it at all:

```
>>> pickle.dumps(feat)
b'\x80\x03c__main__\nmystery\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02X\x03\x00\x00\x00numq\x03K\x01sb.'
```

---

You *do* still want to think about how this class should play with pickling. In particular, do you want unpickling to go through the cache? By default, it doesn't:

```
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(feat)) is feat
False
```

What's happening is that it's using the default [`__reduce_ex__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce_ex__) for pickling, which defaults to doing the equivalent of (only slightly oversimplified):

```
result = object.__new__(__main__.mystery)
result.__dict__.update({'num': 1})
```

If you want it to go through the cache, the simplest solution is this:

```
class mystery:
    @funcy.memoize
    def __new__(cls, num):
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        self.num = num
        return self
    def __reduce__(self):
        return (type(self), (self.num,))
```

---

If you plan to do this a lot, you might think of writing your own class decorator:

```
def memoclass(cls):
    @funcy.memoize
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls)
    cls.__new__ = __new__
    return cls
```

But this:

- … is kind of ugly,
- … only works with classes that don't need to pass constructor arguments to a base class,
- … only works with classes that don't have an `__init__` (or, at least, that have an idempotent and fast `__init__` that's harmless to call repeatedly),
- … doesn't provide an easy way to hook pickling, and
- … doesn't document or test any of those restrictions.

So, I think you're better off being explicit and just memoizing the `__new__` method, or writing (or finding) something a lot fancier that does the introspection needed to make memoizing a class this way fully general. (Or, alternatively, maybe write one that only works with some restricted set of classes—e.g., a `@memodataclass` that's just like `@dataclass` but with a memoized constructor would be a lot easier than a fully general `@memoclass`.)

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks so much. answered all my questions... and more

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is

```
class _mystery(object):

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

@funcy.memoize
def mystery(num):
    return _mystery(num)
```

Comment: Just `mystery = funcy.memoize(_mystery)`